# Create lookup column using AssignedTo column from Task List to Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, lookup-column, tasks, sharepoint-on-prem

I made a task list, and some tasks are assigned to multiple people.
A document webpart gets a filter view, of a selected task in the task list.

When i add a new document to the document library, I'm asked to assign it to a project (i have to choose a lookup column pointing the task title)

So then i select a task and upload a document, **so far it all works.**

however besides the task title, I want to include the "assigned to" people (of the task list). So that i can include a [Me] filter on that field "Assigned To" inside the Document Library.

To see all documents of all the people who where assigned this task.

The problem here, when doing a lookup to a task list from a document library.

I can only see below columns but not **Assigned To**:

- Task Name
- %complete
- Start Date
- ID
- Modified
- Created
- Version
- Taskname (linked to item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Assigned To** column is a Person or Group column, which is **not supported** to be used to create lookup column as what states in the documentation below:
[Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632#__toc245004237)

**As a workaround**, you can create an extra Text column, apply a custom workflow or Event Receiver to copy the value of the **Assigned To** column to this Text column, then you will be able to lookup value from this Text column instead.

About how to copy list item in SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow:

[Copy Item Workflow using SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.salmanghani.info/copy-item-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

**Note :-**

You don't have the copy item in the 2013 workflow engine, indeed. So you just need to choose the 2010 platform. That's where this above link will helps you.

Comment: Strangely i eventually got it working without the second column lookup.
I use the task webpart to filter the document list, while in the document list i show all documents. Now ive changed the tasklist to My Tasks.
Then that would automatically filter the my documents as well. (doing server side rendering of the doc library)
But i give you the answer bonuse since i  made use such a construct later.

Comment: Great than but my answer will also work for same...

Comment: yes the reason i voted your answer :)

Comment: Please upvote as well... :)

Comment: hm my reputation is to low for that here.

Comment: Ok buddy.. that's fine